# Jquery Pagination inside UI slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a Jquery Pagination plugin like used at the bottom of [this page](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/overseas-property-for-sale/UAE-Dubai.html?sortByPriceDescending=true&index=10).

I have seen this kind of plugin some where but I did not find it. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jPaginator](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPaginator) may be the one you are looking for.

See demo over at [remylab.net](http://www.remylab.net46.net/demos/jquery-plugins/jpaginator/).